# how to select child of clicked element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i want to slideToggle the child of clicked element, i tried this ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ESv2g/2/)) but all divs with .description class will slideToggle.
can any one help me?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="item"> <div class="toggle"></div>
    <div class="description"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet  </div>
  </div>


  <div class="item"> <div class="toggle"></div>
    <div class="description"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea c </div>
  </div>


  <div class="item"> <div class="toggle"></div>
    <div class="description"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".toggle").click(function(){
    $(".description").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.row{
    width:900px;
}
.toggle{
    width:150px;
    height:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:red;
}
.item{
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    text-align:center;
}
.description{
    display:none;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to find the sibling element

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".toggle").click(function () {
        $(this).next(".description").slideToggle();
        //$(this).sibling(".description").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9CUCx/)

Comment: thanks this works for element's child, but i have a mistake in my code. description is not child of toggle, so what can i do ?

Comment: @Mohsen yes just fixed see the attached fiddle

Comment: @Mohsen they are sibling elements